# Using PHP to make three columns from array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array with data for a list, and I am trying to automatically create a 3 column list from the array.

In the array, the data is already in alphabetical order, so I want to basically divide the array by 3 to get how many pieces of data there will be in each column, then print them on the screen.

I want the lists to go in order from top to bottom of each column. For example:

```
Col 1      Col 2      Col 3

A          D          G
B          E          H
C          F          I
```

If the number of elements on the array is not evenly divisible by 3, then it would look like:

If there is anything "leftover" (not evenly divisible by 3), then do like so:

```
Col 1      Col 2      Col 3

A          D          G
B          E          H
C          F
```

Each column can contain as many elements as needed.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someting like this should work:

```
$cols  = 3;
$array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');

$columns = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array)/$cols));
```

The chunks devides the array. The ceil of the divided array defines the chunk size

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is accepted.  It doesn't transpose the rows after chunking.  The first row/subarray should contain `a`, `d`, `g`, but this answer gives `a`, `b`, `c`.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/QMJIu

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 function array_chunk_fixed($input, $num, $preserve_keys = FALSE) {
    $count = count($input) ;
    if($count)
        $input = array_chunk($input, ceil($count/$num), $preserve_keys) ;
    $input = array_pad($input, $num, array()) ;
    return $input ;
}


$array = array('A', 'B','C' , 'D', 'E' , 'F', 'G' ,'H');
print_r(array_chunk_fixed($array, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = range('A','H');
$columns = 3;
$chunkedData = array_chunk($data, $columns);
$transposedData = call_user_func_array(
    'array_map',
    array_merge(
        array(NULL),
        $chunkedData
    )
);
displayArray($transposedData);

function displayArray(array $data) {
    foreach($data as $row) {
        echo implode("\t", $row), PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```